# pcl::PointXYZ incomplete type not allowed

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, intellisense, point-cloud-library

I am trying to use the radius search on PCL's KdTreefLANN class. So as a first step I closely followed the tutorial [here](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/kdtree_search.php). However, Visual Studio Code is complaining, that incomplete types are not allowed on line 31. Since this is the exact code from the PointCloud website, I don't know where it fails.

I am using PCL 1.7, GCC 5(.4, I think) on a Linux machine. The includes seem to be found by VS Code. This error occurs before compilation. Compiling the code snippet below works with no errors, but unfortunately compilation of the entire tutorial script fails with some errors (different issue), so I cannot test, if the behavior is as expected.

My questions:

- What is the "incomplete type not allowed" warning implying?
- Where does it come from (in this case)?
- Is it likely to cause unexpected behavior, if compilation succeeds nevertheless (i.e. is this just a problem of VS Code/IntelliSense)?

Code snippet:

```
1 : #include <pcl/point_cloud.h>
2 : #include <pcl/kdtree/kdtree_flann.h>

4 : #include <iostream>
5 : #include <vector>
6 : #include <ctime>

8 : int main (int argc, char** argv)
10: {
11:   srand (time (NULL));

31:   pcl::PointXYZ searchPoint;

33:   searchPoint.x = 1024.0f * rand () / (RAND_MAX + 1.0f);
34:   searchPoint.y = 1024.0f * rand () / (RAND_MAX + 1.0f);
35:   searchPoint.z = 1024.0f * rand () / (RAND_MAX + 1.0f);


81:   return 0;
82: }
```

Comment: Which line is line 31? What is the *exact* compiler output?

Comment: Sorry, I entered the line numbers from the example at the link. Now it should be clear which line is 31.

Answer (score 0):

The type needs to be completely defined for the linking stage of building to succeed. Your program leaves the type incompletely defined because the #include statements you have, only have a forward reference to `pcl::PointXYZ`.

For the complete definition you need to `#include <pcl/point_types.h>`

Comment: Not even the linking stage. The compilation stage can't succeed because the compiler doesn't know how much space to allocate for `searchPoint`, nor whether the x/y/z members exist, nor their types...

Comment: Thank you, but including `point_types.h` unfortunately does not change the phenomenon (at least not for me). Also, since this is code from the tutorial, shouldn't the necessary includes be all there? Could be a mistake of course, but I guess someone would have noticed.
When I open the `point_types.hpp` file, VS Code sees an error in the definition of `struct _PointXYZ` (tag kind of union is incompatible with definition of class...) and the definition of `EIGEN_ALIGN16` (which I guess cannot be defined if `__CUDACC__` is undefined in Eigen's `Macros.h`).